# Tetxtgenrnn save to a specific path

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to save the weights and generated text from running a model to a specific path (such as current directory/results). Is there a parameter I can pass to my train function to specify a path?
Such as:

```
train_function(
    file_path=file,
    new_model=True,
    save_path='./results'
)
```

Currently it is just saving to my root directory.
Also, is there documentation for all of the parameters you can pass to a train function?
Thank, Binkie

Answer (score 0):

Actually you gotta use the generate_to_file function. So, something like:

```
# Use os to get the current path of your models folder
this_file_path = os.path.realpath('models/models_test')

# Generate a name for your file
timestring = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
gen_file = '{}_gentext_{}.txt'.format(model_name, timestring)

textgen.generate_to_file(this_file_path + '/results/' + gen_file,
                         temperature=[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0],
                         prefix=None,
                         n=1000,
                         max_gen_length=300)
```

This should get it to save generated text to a specific file/path.